# Highchart exporting.js error at include

Tags: highcharts

Whenever I include exporting.js (Highcharts JS v5.0.9)file in my html, i get the error

```
<script src="/****/highcharts/exporting.js"></script>

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined
at exporting.js:9
at exporting.js:26
at exporting.js:9
at exporting.js:9
```

On page load I am not plotting the highchart, after selecting some options I plot the chart. Can anyone tell me why this error is coming?

Comment: Do you include http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js before the exporting module?

Comment: i was able to resolve it after i mentioned the version no in my url.